# Redirect unauthorized users using Navigate on screen OnVisible

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I have an issue with Screen On visible parameter condition if user unauthorized else navigate, in case user is not authorized to view a specific in screen, then the user will be redirect to another screen. if there is any another option please provide me with a solution.

```
If(
    IsBlank(
            Param("ID")
   ),
   0,
   If (
        LookUp(
                <<Table_Name>>, 
                <<Field_name>> = Param("ID"),
                <<Field_name>>
              ) = Office365Users.MyProfile().Mail,
        Param("ID"),
        Navigate(Auth_404)
      )
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exact issue are you facing?

Comment: This line "Navigate(Auth_404)" underlined with red. Powerapps doesn't allowed me to add Navigate function on Screen OnVisible property. is there any other option to resolve this issue.

Comment: That's true you cannot navigate from On Screen Visible property, you will have to think of different way.

Comment: What it can be the other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than executing the code `OnVisible` of your first screen, have you considered moving the code to `OnStart` of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can attain this by a workaround,

Have a button 'button_A' with On select =  Navigate(Auth_404) and then change the screen onvisible to

```
If(
IsBlank(
        Param("ID")),0,If (
    LookUp(
            <<Table_Name>>, 
            <<Field_name>> = Param("ID"),
            <<Field_name>>
          ) = Office365Users.MyProfile().Mail,
    Param("ID"),
    Select(button_A)
  ))
```

for more info on [`Trigger OnSelect on a Button`](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Trigger-OnSelect-on-a-Button/td-p/284158)